# Get current local time in UTC and set to Binary operator like >= or <

Tags: swift, date, utc

Bear with me, I'm a newbie to iOS development; I'm currently trying to get the current time in UTC based on the device's local time, and set it in an if / else statement based on the whatever the current time in UTC is.

I've tried the below:

```
let UTCdate = Date()

if (UTCdate >= 13 && UTCdate < 23 {
   // do something
}
```

It's giving me the error that "Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Date' and 'Int'

I know I'm doing something wrong, just don't know what.  Apologies if this has already been asked.  I google'd to the best of my abilities.

Comment: Don't get me wrong but you should first read Apple"s Swift book. (free)  https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4-1/id881256329?mt=11

Comment: It wouldn't be possible in general to compare dates and integers because nothing says what 13 is. 13 days? 13 seconds?

Comment: Apologies, I meant 13 in reference to hour of day; ie 1300 for 1pm.

Comment: @LeoDabus I have the book, been reading through it.  Was just hoping this was something quick and easy I could get figured out!

Comment: "Local time" and "UTC" are conflicting requirements. What time zone do you want to evaluate the current time in?

Comment: @MitchDavis the book is really worth the reading

Comment: @MitchDavis you can use calendar method dataComponents in Timezone to achieve what you want. `let componentsUTC = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!, from: Date())
if 13..<23 ~= componentsUTC.hour! {
    print(true)
}`

Comment: @RobNapier I am wanting to evaluate it in Central Time Zone, my issue is if someone were to load something in the if / else statement from a different time zone during the hours of 1pm to 11pm (in this scenario) the app wouldn't load since they are out of the time zone and it won't load.  Hence why I figured if I chose UTC and just got the current time of UTC and converted it to central time I could be sure they were within the hours I wanted them to view the 'content'.

Comment: rmaddy's answer is what you want, but you want to set the time zone to `TimeZone(identifier: "America/Chicago")`. If you don't mean to evaluate the hour in UTC, don't use UTC. I assume you want DST rules to apply, so you really mean "the current time people in Chicago would see on their clocks." If so, then use that timezone.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your input, rmaddy's answer was exactly what I was looking for.  Appreciate you helping out a noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the hour from your date. `Date` is a timestamp, not an hour. And you need to make sure you extract the hour in the UTC timezone and not locale time.

The following will do what you need:

```
// Create a calendar with the UTC timezone
var utcCal = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.current.identifier) // or hardcode .gregorian if appropriate 
utcCal.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
// The current date
let date = Date()
// Get the hour (it will be UTC hour)
let hour = utcCal.component(.hour, from: date)
if hour >= 13 && hour < 23 {

}
```

If you just use the current calendar to extra the hour from `date` you will get the hour in local time. That is the reason we created a new calendar specific to the UTC timezone (since that is your requirement).

Based on some comments you may not actually want UTC. Simply set the `timeZone` to whatever timezone you actually need.

If you want Chicago time, use:

```
utcCal.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "America/Chicago")!
```

And an alternate to creating your own calendar instance is to use:

```
let hour = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!, from: date).hour!
```

Again, use whatever timezone you need.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked perfectly.  Thank you everyone for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You said "I'm currently trying to get the current time in UTC based on the device's local time". You seem not to understand a key thing about `Date` objects in Cocoa. A `Date` is an instant in time, anywhere on the planet. It doesn't have a time zone. Internally it's represented as an offset from a moment in time that's expressed in UTC, known as the "epoch date", but that's an implementation detail. Imagine that when I capture a `Date` using the call Date(), I snap my fingers and the sound of the finger snap is heard all around the world at the same instant, without even speed-of-light delay. The finger snap is the moment that the call to `Date()` captures.

If I use the code `let date = Date()` I capture the current time all over the planet. A `Date` object doesn't have a specific time of day unless I convert it to a specific time zone. As others have suggested, the `Calendar` method `dateComponents(in:from:)` will let you extract components like the hour **in a specific time zone** from a `Date`, but you need to understand how all this works or you're going to get confused.

I suggest searching on the phrase "Calendrical Calculations" in the Xcode help system and reading that section of the docs. It's very helpful.

Comment: Really appreciate this, you explained it perfectly.